# Can I share a link to my bike question on other StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion

I am a cross country cycling enthusiast and I ran into some legal issues which I am having a hard time getting over. I asked a question on "law" site of stackexchange and it seems like I am outnumbered by cops (maybe?)

I was wondering if I can get your opinion on it.

If it's ok, [here it is](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36393/do-i-need-legal-help-or-medical-mental-help)

Should I delete it and ask again on bicycles.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest no - because its not a question about bicycles directly.

Sorry to hear about your experience, but it is definitely a legal question and off topic for this part of SE.